How to make nginx + php_fpm + cache config file more readable
I have config file like this:
server {
    listen      80;

    server_name domain.com;

    root        /var/www/domain.com/;

    location ~ .\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass                unix:/usr/local/php/sockets/domain.com;

        fastcgi_split_path_info     ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

        include                     fastcgi.conf;

        fastcgi_param               SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param               PATH_INFO   $fastcgi_path_info;

        add_header                  x-pos       php;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(html|htm)$ {
        try_files                   $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php$is_args$query_string;

        fastcgi_cache               my_cache;

        fastcgi_ignore_headers      expires;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers      cache-control;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers      set-cookie;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers      X-Accel-Expires;
        
        # ...

        fastcgi_cache_valid         200 301 302 30d;

        expires                     30d;

        add_header                  x-pos       html;
    }

    #location ~* ^.+\.(html|htm)$ {
    #   fastcgi_pass                    unix:/usr/local/php/sockets/domain.com;
    #
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    #
    #   include                         fastcgi.conf;
    #
    #   fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/index.php;
    #   fastcgi_param                   PATH_INFO   $fastcgi_path_info;
    #
    #   fastcgi_cache                   my_cache;
    #
    #   fastcgi_ignore_headers          expires;
    #   fastcgi_ignore_headers          cache-control;
    #   fastcgi_ignore_headers          set-cookie;
    #   fastcgi_ignore_headers          X-Accel-Expires;
    #   
    #   # ...
    #
    #   fastcgi_cache_valid             200 301 302 30d;
    #
    #   expires                         30d;
    #
    #   add_header                      x-pos       html;
    #}

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    }
}

*.html files are generated by php and suppose to be cached.
However this not work, because location ~* ^.+\.(html|htm)$ is changed to location ~ .\.php(/|$).
The only way I found cache to work is to do the commented location.
However it is very unreadable and I do not like the way it look.
Is there more clean way to do the same? Something that resembles the uncommented config?

The commented way is actually nice because it gets rid of try_files, which has performance impact.
